# Xamarin.Forms: How to add Shell flyout menu item dynamically in the app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, menu, flyout

In my app I would like to enable the user to add menu items which will be displayed in the Flyout.

I have a CRUD function, when you create an item, the item is being saved: [As you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1FFr.png)

In this case I would like that recently created item to be added dynamically in the FlyouItem menu: [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQQYf.png)

Can anyone help me with that?

NOTE: THIS QUESTION IS NOT ANYWHERE ELSE.

Let me know if you need me to share something more.

Comment: if you feel the linked duplicate does not address your question, please explain WHY.  In this case the linked question explains how to dynamically add shell items at runtime, which appears to be the same thing you are asking about.

Comment: What I am asking is similar to that question but is not the SAME. In my application I have a CRUD function, through that function I want to be able to create items dynamically. Am I more clear? @Jason

Comment: I don't really get why that changes the solution.  Dynamically adding a shell item, whether it is based on a CRUD function or a webservice call or anything else, the logic for adding the menu is the same.  Additionally, you haven't post any code that illustrates what you're currently doing, so it is difficult to provide an answer that applies to your specific scenario.  Regardless, you can request to reopen the question.